# Scala trait: How to require output parameter to be Numeric: ambiguous implicit values error

Tags: scala

I'm trying to specify generic function that should return some Number in trait like this:

```
import Numeric.Implicits._

trait ReturnsNumberResult {
  def process[T : Numeric](): T
  def output[T : Numeric](v: T)(implicit numeric: Numeric[T]): String
  def runJob(): Any = {
      output(process())
}
```

When I'm trying to compile this trait I got error:

> ambiguous implicit values: [error]  both object BigIntIsIntegral in
>   object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.BigIntIsIntegral.type
>   [error]  and object IntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type
>   scala.math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral.type [error]  match expected type
>   Numeric[T] [error]       output(process())

What is wrong and how my goal can be achieved?

Comment: I believe this `def output[T: Numeric](v: T)(implicit numeric: Numeric[T])` is redundant. `[T: Numeric]` is just syntactic sugar for the implicit parameter declaration.

Comment: Thanks. You are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by in `runJob` doesn't explicitly declare the **type** of `T: Numeric` for your `output` and `process` method.

So the compiler can't infer type `T: Numeric` for both `output` and `process` method in `runJob` method.

So you can fix it like:

```
  def runJob[T: Numeric](): Any = { //explicitly declare the type T: Numeric
    output[T](process()) // In there we explicitly set the type `T` for output, and for `process` method can auto infer from `output` method
  }
```

Comment: Sorry @chengpohi I was removed an important part from my code to simplify thins. I've added it now. Can you look at it?

Comment: @user2975535, Updated the answer. Hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. But I can't change signature of runJob because I have to follow api. My trait extends api trait